# Ultima compra realizada de un cliente

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, subconsultas

Hola me ayudan con un ejercicio practico en SQL Server que no se como resolverlo. Uso el siguiente modelo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me piden lo siguiente.

AdventureWorks recibió una queja por parte del cliente John Tippett argumentando que se produjo una demora considerable en la entrega de su última compra.
Se desea obtener un detalle de la última compra realizada por dicho cliente, listando: fecha de pedido, fecha de entrega, código y descripción de cada producto, cantidad y precio unitario.

Yo lo intente con una tabla temporal. Pero no se si es correcto el resultado.

```
SELECT s.SalesOrderID,MAX(s.OrderDate) AS 'Fecha de Pedido', MAX(s.DueDate) AS 'Fecha de Entrega'
INTO #ultcomp
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
group by s.SalesOrderID;


SELECT u.[Fecha de Pedido], u.[Fecha de Entrega], pr.ProductNumber AS Codigo, pr.Name AS Descripcion, pr.SafetyStockLevel AS Cantidad, d.UnitPrice AS 'Precio Unitario'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
JOIN Sales.Customer c ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN Person.Person p ON c.PersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
JOIN #ultcomp u ON u.SalesOrderID = s.SalesOrderID 
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail d ON s.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
JOIN Production.Product pr ON d.ProductID = pr.ProductID 
WHERE p.FirstName = 'John' AND p.LastName = 'Tippett'
```

Gracias!

Comment: Qué has intentado? Puedes agregar el código SQL donde muestras tus avances y donde estás teniendo dificultades? De lo contrario, parece que nos estás pidiendo que hagamos tu tarea por ti; y ese no es el caso, verdad?

Comment: Por favor pulsa Editar en tu pregunta y no olvides añadir el código SQL en forma de texto, y cualquier otro detalle que consideres necesario.

Comment: Ahi lo pude agregar.

Comment: Si el ejercicio te pide la última compra, puedes ordenar por fecha de manera descendente y hacer un `SELECT TOP 1`, no?

Comment: Si si tenia una alternativa con esa tambien, que es ordenar por fecha y hacer el TOP 1 para que me de solo un solo registro. Pero como me pedian una que haga con tablas temporables lo buscaba plantear como lo hice arriba.